# Что заначит статус запроса canceled при отправке формы?

Tags: html, form

Не могу найти в интернете, что значит статут запроса `canceled` в закладке Networks в DevTools?
Я получаю этот статус, когда просто отправляю форму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: предположу, что запрос отменен с помощью javascript (event.preventDefault = true), но я не уверен

Comment: @yurish, `preventDefault` - это функция. И она не способна остановить запрос, только отменяет стандартную реакцию браузера. А вот отменить загрузку может многое - прервалась связь, DNS провалился, Боги разгневались и повелели серверу резко и без объяснений прервать связь...

Comment: а в консоли нет сообщений? может быть, имеет место что-то типа отправки несекьюрной формы с https-страницы. тогда в консоли должно быть сообщение от браузера.